# How to git clone both origin and upstream?

Tags: git, clone

Context: I am working with git. I typically have forks of other repositories where I contribute now and then. I switch my work machines often - and also delete local clones of the remote repositories. When I want to resume work, I need to do following:

1. git clone https://github.com/example-upstream/repo
2. cd repo
3. git remote rename origin upstream
4. git remote add origin https://github.com/example-fork/repo
5. git fetch origin
6. git push origin # to push the main branch from upstream to origin

For step 6, there is [`git-town sync`](https://www.git-town.com/commands/sync). I checked [hub](https://hub.github.com/) and [gh](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_clone).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use [`gh repo clone <fork-url>`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_clone):

```
gh repo clone https://github.com/example-fork/repo
```

This does all of steps 1 to 5:

```
$ gh repo clone https://github.com/example-fork/repo 
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 410, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (151/151), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
remote: Total 410 (delta 80), reused 139 (delta 78), pack-reused 259
Receiving objects: 100% (410/410), 79.42 KiB | 2.48 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (212/212), done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 16, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 9), reused 15 (delta 9), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), 4.33 KiB | 119.00 KiB/s, done.
From github.com:example-upstream/repo
 * [new branch]      master         -> upstream/master
 * [new tag]         release-2023.2 -> release-2023.2
! Repository example-upstream/repo set as the default repository. To learn more about the default repository, run: gh repo set-default --help
```

Install it on Windows using `winget install --id GitHub.cli`.

More installation instructions: https://github.com/cli/cli#installation